# google cloud billing API: not able to update billing info

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-billing

I am trying to learn how to use the cloud billing API and playing around with it's methods. I copied a code snippet in Java that shows how to use the updateBillingInfo method. I have a project in my cloud account, and it has a billing account associated with it, and I wanted to change it to a different billing account.
Here's what I tried:

```
String name = "projects/My project";
ProjectBillingInfo info = new ProjectBillingInfo();
info.setBillingAccountName("billingAccounts/$BILLING_ID");
Cloudbilling.Projects.UpdateBillingInfo request = cloudbillingService.projects().updateBillingInfo(name, info);
ProjectBillingInfo response = request.execute();
```

and my problem is that request.execute() (as well as the API browser explorer) throws an exception with code "500 - internal error encountered".
Am I not using it correctly? It was my understanding that after this, when I check my project in GCP, I should see my project listed to the new billing account. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an invalid Project ID,  since GCP project IDs have no spaces in them. Note that Project IDs and Project names are different [things](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects). It needs to be the ID as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateBillingInfo#path-parameters). The rest of your code snippet seems fine, just make sure you put the actual project ID like this: projects/your-project-id